# Application Insights: Telling the clients apart in the application map

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using Application Insights in multi-component mode, all my telemetry goes to one AI resource. I have two web apps that run an in-browser client each.

In the application map, I correctly get all a rectangle for all the different parts of the system - except for the client business. All client activity shows as "Client: production": ("production" is the name of the AI resource.)

[image]

There are actually two such "Client: production" rectangles, each one visible only when selecting the respective server app. That sounds about right, *but*: If I click on related metrics, I get this filter:

[image]

That obviously contains metrics for all clients, not just the selected one. Is there no way to properly separate the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a current limitation of multi-component application map that neither Availability nor Client telemetry honor multi-component. We're working on fixing it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.